# git - some files are not at the latest commit in remote

Tags: git, merge, version-control, gitlab

Our git repository seems to be 'ignoring' some commits we pushed over a time period. I can see them in the commit history, but when opening / pulling the actual file, it appears to be at an earlier commit.

The remote is a Gitlab hosted by our University. Neither me nor my teammates recall doing anything out of the ordinary, and nothing unusual shows up in the repository history either. We only have one remote branch (master).

I made and pushed the commits last Thursday, and Teammate A did a pull from the repository immediately after and pulled the changes that I had just pushed. Teammate B pushed a couple of commits after that. According to `git show` and the history shown in Gitlab, Teammate B's commits did not affect the files changed in the earlier commits I made. However,  when both me and Teammate A did a pull following Teammate B's commits, the files were overwritten from an earlier commit.

Example:

1. Commit history for one of the affected files
   [image: Commit history for one of the affected files]

The latest commit is `9c53751e` but when we pull from remote, we get `b690a169` instead.

2. git log output for the same file for the same time period

```
commit b690a169b9293d41cd0aa7c0984cc5800aa7dc6b
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 00:28:31 2019 +0000
```

redacted - commit message

commit b8ecd472ce00dd71f7fd182a6fac687e7a1127b8
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Mon Mar 11 20:41:16 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 19a93adaa7c8f5cf0bafb9af2ad053cff8113419
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sat Feb 23 23:52:06 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit f0f1a60d57e54d1b5148f4c163d26275d947c9e8
Merge: a307998 0d0dd67
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sat Feb 23 16:09:35 2019 +0000

:...skipping...
commit b690a169b9293d41cd0aa7c0984cc5800aa7dc6b
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 00:28:31 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit b8ecd472ce00dd71f7fd182a6fac687e7a1127b8
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Mon Mar 11 20:41:16 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 19a93adaa7c8f5cf0bafb9af2ad053cff8113419
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sat Feb 23 23:52:06 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit f0f1a60d57e54d1b5148f4c163d26275d947c9e8
Merge: a307998 0d0dd67
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sat Feb 23 16:09:35 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit a30799825ca0776513fd62468fca436bcaa04ab7
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sat Feb 23 13:17:58 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 0d0dd67664c63905f3b3a4061a1690a86d5da117
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Feb 21 12:30:53 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 280e11a7315e761440f38257cdffdbd79ea77513
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sun Feb 17 15:24:04 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 61bbc6da1e1e22f42df1f9b0141dabdaf3b132e5
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Sun Feb 17 12:21:38 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

Commit `9c53751e` doesn't appear anywhere in git log for this file. However, I find it interesting that some commits appear repeatedly (it repeats after the 4th commit from the top).

3. git log for the entire repository

commit f52a9891dce9d1fc04287a0cc036ba7a6abfe490
Merge: 37f2c7a 9c53751
Author: Teammate B
Date:   Fri Mar 15 12:10:29 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 37f2c7a2da1c7154edc25542b831cf47e602c779
Author: Teammate B
Date:   Fri Mar 15 09:52:12 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 9c53751e8b6edf6222f3dd7117b0ebf3a640bc68
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Mar 14 21:27:33 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 1c9eb7142a69e67e5c5459a4366dd125c9a85696
Merge: cb01aa8 669d5d1
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 21:22:58 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit cb01aa82a1a5ab6b311e7cd97a1add29217df2c7
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 21:22:48 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 669d5d143e4b2f3734f0cdabc98ade0914f6d2ea
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 21:02:26 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit 8117b7b68cdb4763728eb93acfc476d2ffc47a3b
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 20:52:02 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

commit ac8429422a1eb5698e772efa0fe7d513cf35d41b
Author: redacted - author
Date:   Thu Mar 14 20:18:13 2019 +0000

redacted - commit message

In this git log, the two latest commits are the ones made by Teammate B. The 'missing' commit, `9c53751e`, does appear here. Teammate B's commits haven't affected any files affected by `9c53751e` (verified by using `git show f52a9891dce9d1fc04287a0cc036ba7a6abfe490`), however `9c53751e` is listed as a merge parent.

All commits made and pushed on Friday and afterwards work as expected, the remote points to the latest commit. This includes files affected by the issue described above.

I suspect it's a merge gone wrong, however it's odd that no information can be found in the history. Are there any other git commands I could run to provide some explanation? Is there any way of restoring these commits without manually going through the history for each file and stitching it together?